# Flex: rounded corners for dynamic created images

Tags: apache-flex

there a better way as this [example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/09/09/rounding-the-corners-of-an-image-control-in-flex-using-a-mask/)

to create round corners for dynamic (addChild or addElement) created Images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, here is a custom class http://santobay.blogspot.com/2010/04/rounded-corner-image-in-flex.html . save this code as com/RoundedImage.as , create new mxml file with this code

```
<mx:Application name="Image_mask_test"
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"         xmlns:custom="com.*"
    layout="vertical"
    verticalAlign="middle"
    backgroundColor="white">

<mx:HBox id="hbox" width="100%">
    <custom:RoundedImage source="images/test.jpg" width="250" height="250" cornerRadius="15"/>
</mx:HBox></mx:Application>
```

and compile. For create images dynamic use this code:

```
<fx:Script>
   <![CDATA[
   import com.RoundedImage;
   public function createImage():void {
    var newImage:RoundedImage = new RoundedImage();
    newImage.source = "images/test.jpg";
    newImage.cornerRadius = 20;
    hbox.addChild(newImage);
    } 
    ]]>
 </fx:Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you must use a mask, if you add it dynamically.
However, you could add a 'frame' on top of the image, if the background is solid, you can use this trick.